# Help rearranging differential equation??

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Need to rearrange the following equation to solve for E:

$$ V\cdot\frac{d\delta_L}{dt}+\delta_L\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}= I\cdot\delta_I-O\cdot\delta_O-E\cdot\delta_E \tag{1}$$

Am I allowed to just do the following?

$$-1\cdot((V\cdot\frac{d\delta_L}{dt}+\delta_L\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}-I\cdot\delta_I+O\cdot\delta_O)/\delta_E) = E \tag{2}$$

Where $\dfrac{d\delta_L}{dt} = \delta_{Lf} - \delta_{Li} \dots$ and similar for $\dfrac{dV}{dt}\dots$ I have $V_i$ and $V_f$ and $\delta_{Li}$ and $\delta_{Lf}$ and also have the fluxes from the right hand side during the interval $dt$ of $(1)$ (with the exception of $E$).

I feel like I am supposed to integrate or something but have no idea how! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I may not even be asking this question right. Could use help rephrasing it for better chance of an answer.

Comment: Are these all scalar quatities?

Comment: Yea, it's a mass balance equation. δ values are isotopic signatures of each flux parameter (the unit is permille) and the rest of the variables are volumes ($m^3$).